# Why is audio high pitched over HDMI?

Tags: audio, hdmi

When I connect my Windows 8 notebook to my television via HDMI the audio is higher pitched than it should be. If I use a different audio output this does not occur, and note the audio is not sped up at all, simply higher pitched.

What could this be caused by?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is an issue with the sample rate based upon my own music experience, but, I can't back it up with fact... Is there a way to configure either sample rate (Hz)?

Comment: you need to determine if it your HDMI output, or the TV.  Do you have another TV or monitor with HDMI input that you can connect that notebook to?

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue. My notebook's sound was set to 96kHz but my HDMI speakers set to 48kHz. Change your notebook's sample rate to 48kHz and reconnect your HDMI and the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your TV set (what TV model is this?) was set by someone (even by mistake) to have higher pitch on HDMI input channel. Many TV models have this functionality, what for? I don't know, maybe karaoke? :) Plug in HDMI then enter TV sound settings and search for pitch-like settings.